I Have many request to display page?
When I visit any app page this overload happens, Is this normal!? I do not know what code caused this problem.
 POST /user 200 in 3605ms
 POST /user 200 in 488ms
 POST /user 200 in 48ms
 POST /user 200 in 70ms
 POST /user 200 in 361ms
 POST /user 200 in 37ms
 POST /user 200 in 340ms
 POST /user 200 in 36ms
 POST /user 200 in 33ms
 POST /user 200 in 719ms
 POST /user 200 in 40ms
 POST /user 200 in 38ms
 POST /user 200 in 599ms
 POST /user 200 in 41ms
 POST /user 200 in 45ms
 POST /user 200 in 802ms
 POST /user 200 in 651ms
 POST /user 200 in 573ms
 POST /user 200 in 542ms

[updated]
The problem is that the pages in my app have a lot of requests to fetch one page, like this code above. These are a lot of requests to display the user page.
I was unsure what to share because I did not know what caused this problem. But now after tries, I think what caused this problem when fetching the cart. I am not sure yet! Why does this problem happen?
export default function Cart({ token }) {
   const t = useTranslations("cart");
   const { cart: cartLocal, total: totalFu, isCartUpdated } = useCart();
   const [total, setTotal] = useState(0);
   const [cartLength, setCartLength] = useState(0);
   const [cart, setCart] = useState([]);
   const totalAmount = totalFu({ cart });
   const { currencyShortname } = useCurrency();
   const locale = useLocale();

   useEffect(() => {
      (async () => {
         if (token) {
            const { data } = await fetchData({
               endPoint: '/cart/items',
               token,
               locale,
            });
            setCart([]);
            setTotal(0);
            setCartLength(0);
            if (!Array.isArray(data)) { // If data array its now empty.
               setCart(data?.products);
               setTotal(data?.total);
               setCartLength(data?.products.length);
            }
         } else {
            setCart(cartLocal);
            setTotal(totalAmount);
            setCartLength(cart.length);
         }
      })();

   }, [cart.length, cartLocal, locale, token, totalAmount, isCartUpdated]);


If there is token I am work on cart from API

Else work on local cart


Here my cart is not updating immediately in the UI when I operate on it (update, delete, etc...). I use the isCartUpdated variable to call this logic in the useEffect hook agin when added or delete ... from the cart to update it immediately. By calling this function updateCart below. But this is not an efficient solution

  const handleAddToCart = async () => {
    const userLogged = await isUserLogged();
    if (userLogged) {
      const { message, status } = await addToCart(product.id);
      if (status !== "success") {
        toastError(message || t('add-fail'));
        return;
      }
      updateCart();
      toastSuccess(message || t('add-success'));
    } else {
      addToCartLocal(product);
      toastSuccess(t('add-success'));
    }
  };


It's a bit hard to tell what exactly is causing this. Where are you requesting a POST to /user? Are these requests going on infinitely or a finite amount of times? Often it means that you're passing in a bad dependency to a useEffect. This particularly happens when passing objects or functions that have been not memoized as a useEffect dependency which causes an infinite re-render loop.

For useEffect you have some dependencies states and in the useEffect body you are changing the states values.
When each of dependencies have change the useEffect body will run again.
That's the problem.

For useEffect you have some dependencies states and in the useEffect body you are changing the states values. When each of dependencies have change the useEffect body will run again.
That's the problem.
You need to just have dependencies on variables which you are using them to call the API.
Read more about useEffect.
useEffect(() => {
  (async () => {
     if (token) {
        const { data } = await fetchData({
           endPoint: '/cart/items',
           token,
           locale,
        });
        setCart([]);
        setTotal(0);
        setCartLength(0);
        if (!Array.isArray(data)) { // If data array its now empty.
           setCart(data?.products);
           setTotal(data?.total);
           setCartLength(data?.products.length);
        }
     } else {
        setCart(cartLocal);
        setTotal(totalAmount);
        setCartLength(cart.length);
     }
  })();
}, [locale, token]);

